# Tracking stats for API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, statistics, analytics

I am currently developing a REST API in Rails 5. I am wondering if there is a gem or self-hosted tool (preferably not Google or a service that requires external data sharing) that I can use to provide usage statistics of my API (url, parameters provided, response times, HTTP status and, if possible, user_id etc).

My goal with this, is to determine which methods/functionality are used most, how these methods are performing and where I should plan optimizations and refactoring.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Unfortunately not. It seems to me I have to make something myself then.

Comment: Did you end up trying coverband?

Comment: Not yet, but you are right, this may very well be the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I know of something that might work for your needs. Now this gem does not track the actual usage of your API but to the end of you optimization goal:

> My goal with this, is to determine which methods/functionality are
>   used most, how these methods are performing and where I should plan
>   optimizations and refactoring

Coverband will tell you what methods are being executed so you can assess usage hotspots. Hope this helps!

https://github.com/danmayer/coverband